# How to disable all Kendo TreeView nodes without collapsed

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I use kendo.ui.TreeView for jQuery. I created tree with checkbox and child objects:

```
$("#my-tv-1").kendoTreeView({
  dataSource: data,
  checkboxes: {
    checkChildren: true
  },
  loadOnDemand: false
}).data("kendoTreeView");

let data = [
  { text: "Item 1", id: 1 },
  { text: "Item 2", id: 2 },
  { 
    text: "Item 3", expanded: true, items: [
      { text: "Subitem 1", id: 10 }
    ]
  }
];
```

How to disable all nodes (or all treeview) without collapsed nodes? When I use "enable" method all nodes that have child elements and have been expanded are collapsed.

```
function() {
  let treeview = $("#my-tv-1").data("kendoTreeView");

  // Disable all items
  treeview.enable(false);

  // or any node
  let n = treeview.dataSource.view()[2];
  treeview.enable(n, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable, you can do something like this so that the expanded nodes are not collapsed:

```
treeview.element.find('input.k-checkbox').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'true');
});

treeview.element.find('span.k-in').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('k-state-disabled');
});

treeview.element.find('span.k-i-collapse').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('k-state-disabled');
});
```

To enable them back:

```
treeview.enable(true);
```

Comment: The first time works fine (disable, then enable), the second time doesn't work (disable - Yes, enable doesn't work anymore).

Comment: Open up devtools. Investigate the HTML and its attributes. See what has changed or what is different. Analyse it. If it works then there is no reason why it should not work again. A computer does what it is told to do. You could reverse what you did and not use `treeview.enable(true)`.